# JSON throw undefined in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Please help me I am new in API integration
I want to show Poster, Title and year from API url.
here is the code which i tried, when i log, its shows JSON in array but its throw undefined in front end please help.

Thanks in advance

```
      <html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <title>Welcome</title>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <h1>Movies</h1>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive table-striped" id="movies_table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Poster</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Year</th>
                </tr>       

            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="my_div" class="hide">"Thank You"</div>

</body>
  <script>

  $(document).ready(function(){
           $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=d8ecb486&s=red", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            var movies = '';
            $.each(data, function(key,value){
              movies += '<tr>';
              movies += '<td>'+value.poster+'</td>';
              movies += '<td>'+value.title+'</td>';
              movies += '<td>'+value.year+'</td>';
              movies += '</tr>';
            });
            $('#movies_table').append(movies);

           });
  });
</script>
</html>
```

here is the API structure

```
{"Search":[{"Title":"RED","Year":"2010","imdbID":"tt1245526","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMzg2Mjg1OTk0NF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjQ4MTA3Mw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Red Dragon","Year":"2002","imdbID":"tt0289765","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ4MDgzNjM5MF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwMjUwMzY2._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The Hunt for Red October","Year":"1990","imdbID":"tt0099810","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BY2Y5NWVjMmQtMWRmOC00ZTg3LWI3YWQtZGI2MWUwNWQ4OWQ2XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNDk3NzU2MTQ@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"The Thin Red Line","Year":"1998","imdbID":"tt0120863","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYjEzMTM2NjAtNWFmZC00MTVlLTgyMmQtMGQyNTFjZDk5N2NmXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNzQ1ODk3MTQ@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"RED 2","Year":"2013","imdbID":"tt1821694","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjI2ODQ4ODY3Nl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNTc2NzE1OQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Red Sparrow","Year":"2018","imdbID":"tt2873282","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTA3MDkxOTc4NDdeQTJeQWpwZ15BbWU4MDAxNzgyNTQz._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Red Eye","Year":"2005","imdbID":"tt0421239","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNzAxNjc1ODczOF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwMjE3MjEzMw@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Red Riding Hood","Year":"2011","imdbID":"tt1486185","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc4NjYyMzQ5MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNjE5Mjc3NA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Three Colors: Red","Year":"1994","imdbID":"tt0111495","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BYTg1MmNiMjItMmY4Yy00ZDQ3LThjMzYtZGQ0ZTQzNTdkMGQ1L2ltYWdlL2ltYWdlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyMTQxNzMzNDI@._V1_SX300.jpg"},{"Title":"Red Dawn","Year":"2012","imdbID":"tt1234719","Type":"movie","Poster":"https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMjI0MDAwMzA1M15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNzIxMjY3OA@@._V1_SX300.jpg"}],"totalResults":"3993","Response":"True"}
```

Comment: Please edit to show the exact error. Don't make us guess. Also, your request for tutorials is off topic for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are multiple things

First of all your actual data is coming under Search Array

secondly the key you're trying to read is starting from Uppercase

then if you iterate through search array key will be index like 0,1,2...n and you need to read from value

just update this logic and you're good to go

```
var movies = '';
$.each(response.Search, function(key,value){
  movies += `<tr>
  <td>${value.Poster}</td>
  <td>${value.Title}</td>
  <td>${value.Year}</td>
  </tr>`;
});
$('#movies_table').append(movies);
```

Comment: you're welcome  please consider upvote and close this question if you found this helpful.

Comment: will you please help me to  display only movies released after the year 2000 on a mobile device

Comment: just simply add `if (value.Year < 2000) return` in first line of $.each loop

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your each loop, you need to use key.poster instead of `value.poster`. The first argumemnt to loop specifies the data element.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
       $.getJSON("http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=d8ecb486&s=red", function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        var movies = '';
        $.each(data, function(key,value){
          movies += '<tr>';
          movies += '<td>'+key.poster+'</td>';
          movies += '<td>'+key.title+'</td>';
          movies += '<td>'+key.year+'</td>';
          movies += '</tr>';
        });
        $('#movies_table').append(movies);

       });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, @prince  for your reply
but its showing same error

Comment: Can you please update the question with the data structure you are receiving from API.